Will every object in the universe evaporate?
According to a recent paper (explained here) every massive object in the universe will evaporate in a similar way into Black Holes through Hawking radiation.
I've seen some critical comments to the paper indicating that it's wrong in many aspects, but the authors do not seem convinced of these critics
Therefore, even if the authors are correct and the paper is right, would all objects in the universe evaporate? Would there be any way to avoid it? Would even individual massive particles "evaporate"?

Wondrak et al.   have been discussed at PSE here. That paper is most certainly wrong.

Thats what the authors claim so why ask us?

Since the Hawking radiation has not been experimentally observed or even predicted by a confirmed theory, isn’t it a bit premature to talk about everything evaporating? Also what is the practical meaning of the $10^{100}$-year timescale other than using physics formulas for entertainment?

@A.V.S. I also asked one of the authors whether their model would apply to individual particles and he said that it was not clear. So, if it does not apply in those situations, would you say that it applies to diffuse clouds or halos or particles like neutrinos (around gslaxies) or electrons (in interestellsr gas) that are not fully clumped into compact structures?
